# Slice not targeting all instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of spans throughout my page, in which i am using a class to control various styles.  When a condition changes I want to apply changes to those classes at the same time.

example:

```
<SPAN class="zrow_1">...</SPAN>
<SPAN class="zrow_2">...</SPAN>
<SPAN class="zrow_3">...</SPAN>
```

...
...
more code down the page
...
...

```
<SPAN class="zrow_1">...</SPAN>
<SPAN class="zrow_2">...</SPAN>
<SPAN class="zrow_3">...</SPAN>
```

Now I know I can target each class individually and that works great.  But to clean up my code and save me some time i was trying to use slice.

```
$("SPAN[class^='zrow_']").slice(2).css({'display': 'none'});
```

now the above works for the first instance on the page hiding the spans as I want; however, the second set of spans are not.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using slice, you are only taking the first two results in the entire page, not in each group of elements. I would use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for this:

```
$("SPAN[class^='zrow_']").filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).prop("class").substring(5),10) <= 2;
}).hide();
```

This will return all `zrow_1` and `zrow_2` elements. You can change that hardcoded `2` to however many elements you want to apply the action to.

[<kbd>Example jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/CU7F6/1/)

Comment: _"By using slice, you are only taking the first two results in the entire page"_. Not true. `.slice()` with a single argument will return everything from that element to the end of the array.

Comment: j08691 is right, slice would bring back the tail of the list rather than the head. It's still not the right approach to the problem though :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the selector you have will return all six, but you're only hiding two of them.

I would just go with the class names and separate them by comma.

```
$("span.zrow_1, span.z_row_2").css({'display': 'none'});
```

Comment: while this would work not very suitable to reproduce on a larger scale.

Comment: It really depends on the purpose.  You could always generate the selector with a for loop or any other method.  The problem with other solutions are that they are less efficient.  While here wouldn't make much difference, but may affect performance on a large scale.  First you're doing a fuzzy search which is more taxing than a class search, returning everything, then filtering.  Plus it obfuscates the code.  Although it's a good way to learn about new techniques, I would go for efficient and readable in production.  But that's just me.

Answer (score -1):

I could see what the problem is. The index in slice is zero-based.

Check : https://api.jquery.com/slice/.

Change the $("SPAN[class^='zrow_']").slice(2).css({'display': 'none'}); to

$("SPAN[class^='zrow_']").slice(1).css({'display': 'none'}); that should work.

Thanks is much appreciated.